# i want to remove integers from a string but not all integers only few integers in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
    Name           Value     Volume
0  2019 sai 20     21321       23
1  2020 James      12311       12
2  2018 Adi 35     4435        11
3  2017 Hello 46   32454       34
4  2019 Girl       654654      56
5  2018 surya 25   325874      89
```

I want to get a output like this:

```
    Name       Value     Volume
0   sai 20     21321       23
1   James      12311       12
2   Adi 35     4435        11
3   Hello 46   32454       34
4   Girl       654654      56
5   surya 25   325874      89
```

Can anyone help me how to do this.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `jupyter-notebook` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `pandas`).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to remove a prefix only.
You can do it like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{"Name" : "2019 sai 20", "Value":23, "Volume":23},
                   {"Name" : "2020 James", "Value":23, "Volume":23}])

df["Name"] = df["Name"].str[5:]
```